# Ошибка при компиляции wxWidgets приложения! Уже три недели не могу справится!

Tags: c++, codeblocks

С::В выдает:

> ||can't popen `gcc -E -xc -DRC_INVOKED -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\mswud C:\Users\TIMONI~1\Desktop\Queue\PROGRA~2\Lw11\Lw11.3\resource.rc': No error|

При запуске .exe приложения:
[image: При запуске .exe приложения:]

В настройках компилятора добавил команду:

> windres.exe --use-temp-file

C ней приложение в С::B работает но сам файл exe нет.

Comment: У Вас компилятор установлен? Пробовали собирать консольное приложение типа "хелловорда"? Почему взяли ветку 3.1 (она для разработчиков), а не 3.0.3 (стабильная)? Бинарные файлы библиотеки откуда брали (*.lib, *.dll)?

Comment: Бинарные файлы беру с *dll так как выбрал SHARED=1.Я установил 3.0.4 но и так выдает ту же ошибку: ||can't popen `gcc -E -xc -DRC_INVOKED -IC:\wxWidgets-3.0.4\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.0.4\lib\gcc_dll\mswud C:\Users\TIMONI~1\Desktop\Queue\TRD\test\resource.rc': No error|

Comment: Пока остается слишком много причин, по которым может быть такое сообщение... По идее, ресурсные файлы должны обрабатываться своим компилятором (windres.exe). Возможно, в настройках компилятора C::B у Вас неверно задан путь или имя windres. Может быть, не та версия (перепутаны 32 или 64 битные). Может просто нет места для временного файла на диске, где определен системный временный каталог. В итнернетах пишут даже, что могут быть виноваты настройки переменной окружения `COMSPEC` (если изменяли).

Comment: TDM-GCC-32 - компилятор. Консольные приложения работают как надо. A што ето за "windres.exe"? B C::B "Resurs compiler" указан на "windres.exe"

Comment: Это компилятор ресурсов. Грубо говоря, нужен, чтобы из файла описаний оконных ресурсов (файлы .res, .rc) сделать объектный файл, который можно линковать к остальной части программы. А вот как по человечески объяснить что такое "ресурсы"?... Могу ошибаться, но кажется это описание виджетов, их подписи (строки), взаимное расположение и т.п. То, что Вы в GUI редакторе настраиваете (в wxSmith). Саму прграмму можете увидеть там же, где находится gcc.exe, g++.exe (т.е. в каталоге `bin` компилятора).

Comment: Можно попробовать скормить параметр этому `windres`... В настройках компилятора у C::B внизу списка программ - есть настройка и для windres. Можно попробовать ему добавить опцию: `windres.exe  --use-temp-file` - это заставит его вместо канала (вызова `popen`) использовать временный файл. В документации пишут, что это иногда может решить проблему, когда в системе не удается открыть канал (но там отсылки про windows 95/98... это же не Ваш случай?)

Comment: PS: вспомнил :-) - еще к ресурсам обычно относят иконки, звуки, рисунки и подобные объекты.

Comment: Это очень странно. Скорее всего, в системе проблема осталась, просто конкретно для wxWidgets ее удалось обойти...

Comment: Ну оно же русским языком написало - положите эту DLL (из комплекта wx) в каталог с Вашей программой ;-). Или (худший вариант) в системные каталоги, типа %windows%\system32. После этого, программа может захотеть и другие DLL (если у Вас в системе не прописаны пути для gcc) - из каталога исполняемых файлов gcc.